# LaTeX enumerate - bold item with non-bold text

Tags: lists, environments, enumerate, bold, enumitem

I'm trying to customize the environment `enumerate` where the `\item` is bold but the text is not bold. What I've tried is (at the suggestion of one of the google-results):

```
\let\origitem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\normalfont\origitem}
\newcommand{\bolditem}{\normalfont\bfseries\origitem}
```

and then use it with

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \bolditem[0] First item (whole line is bold)
    \bolditem[1] Second item (also bold)
    \item[2] Third item (not bold)
\end{enumerate}
```

But this makes the whole line bold. I only want the numbered part to be bold.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: A quick work-around is using \normalfont{} around the text that should not be bold.

If someone knows a way to do this in the \newcommand, that will still be very appreciated and I will mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `enumitem` package. If you don't want to use additional packages, you can simply redefine `\labelenumi`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \renewcommand\labelenumi{\bfseries\theenumi}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
    \item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

% requires the enumitem package
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\arabic*]
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
    \item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: on a more programmatic level, you could define a new list-like environment that behaves like the standard `enumerate`, but with the desired format for the label. This can be done using something like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{boenumerate}
  {\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textbf\theenumi}}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{boenumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
    \item Third item.
\end{boenumerate}

\end{document}
```

or imitating the definition of the `enumerate` environment as given in `source2e`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\boenumerate{%
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textbf\theenumi}
  \ifnum \@enumdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
      \expandafter
      \list
        \csname label\@enumctr\endcsname
        {\usecounter\@enumctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}
\let\endboenumerate =\endlist
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{boenumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
    \item Third item.
\end{boenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Something similar, but now with the help of the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{boenumerate}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[boenumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\begin{boenumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
    \item Third item.
\end{boenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution `\def\boenumerate` is in my opinion bad. You should use something like: `\newenvironment{boenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand*\labelenumi{....`.

Comment: @Marco: why is it bad? I know that you can define `boenumerate` as you did, but I also wanted to show how the standard `enumerate` environment is defined in the kernel.

Comment: I think the definition in the kernel is very strange to many users. So I think we should present a simple solution by `LaTeX2e` user commands.
I doesn't mean that the solution is wrong ;-)

Comment: @Marco: agreed. I've added a note to my answer.

Comment: Now you have nearly every solution ;-) Few minutes ago I got an idea to complete this by creating a new environment by `\list{}{} ....\endlist` :-)

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: The last code example is exactly what I was looking for, thank you :)

Answer (score 13):

You should use a package like `enumitem`. The package allows to modify the `item` by a key-value-syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*},start=0]
   \item First item
   \item Second item
   \item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't address the question, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to redefine `\item`, as it's used in many parts of LaTeX. Here is a `\benumerate` environment in which you can use the `\bolditem` command alternating it to the normal one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\let\ifbolditem\iffalse
\def\bolditemtrue{\global\let\ifbolditem\iftrue}
\def\bolditemfalse{\global\let\ifbolditem\iffalse}

\newenvironment{benumerate}
  {\def\bolditem{\bolditemtrue\item}%
   \enumerate
   \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\hss\llap{\ifbolditem\bfseries\fi##1\bolditemfalse}}}
  {\endenumerate}


\begin{document}
\begin{benumerate}
\item Normal
\bolditem Bold
\item Normal again
\bolditem[9] Bold
\end{benumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is *almost* the same answer I posted to a related (identical?) question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347965/103825). I am re-posting most of it here for the sake of those finding these posts via Google search.

There are two different solutions, one local and one global, using the `enumitem` package.

The idea for both is to use the `font=` key for `enumitem`.

**Local:** Every time you want an individual `enumerate` environment with bold numbers/letters/numerals (whatever the setting is), just use:

```
\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries]
*your code here*
\end{enumerate}
```

Note that this solution is *strictly* local -- the font settings will be *not* be inherited by `enumerate` environments contained/nested within outer `enumerate` environments for which the setting does not hold -- [see another of my related answers here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347968/103825).

**Global:** If you know in advance that you will want *every* `enumerate` environment to have bold numbers/letters/numerals (whatever the setting is), then put the following in the document's preamble:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{font=\bfseries}
```

*Note:* As a general rule of thumb, it is preferable to use the `font=` key for `enumitem` (as opposed to the `label=` key suggested in other answers) if all you want to do is to make the numbers/letters/etc. bold. `label=` completely overwrites the standard settings of enumerate, while `font=` just modifies them.

---

Source: I read the [documentation](http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for `enumitem`, and both of the above solutions worked for me using TeXstudio and XeLaTeX compiler.

Answer (score 1):

By using `enumerate` package you can also use this command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries a.]
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```