# Creating lists with items separated by a rule

Tags: lists, rules

How can I create a list in which a rule is automatically inserted between each pair of items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***2014-07-23:*** Updated to support optional parameter of `\item`.

---

An alternate method that you can use is to redefine `\item`. This is not necessarily a better solution in this case, but you don't need to rely on the internals of other packages. I use a modified version of the rule that @Werner defined in his solution, but that can be adjusted as desired.

Here I use `etoolbox` to handle the condition that we do not want to apply the rule above the very first `\item`. I prefer this method of handling conditions, but any other method 
for
[Conditional typesetting / build](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577)
can be used as well.

First step is to save the original definition of item

```
\LetLtxMacro{\OriginalItem}{\item}%
```

As we are redefining a macro with optional parameters, we use `\LetLtxMacro` from [the `letltxmacro` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) . A detailed description of `\LetLtxMacro` can be found at this question at [closed square root symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29837/4301).

Now using this we can define our own version of item:

```
\newcommand{\ItemWithRuleAbove}[1][]{%
    \iftoggle{IsFirstItem}{}{\WernersHRule}% only add \hrule if not first item
    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{\OriginalItem }{\OriginalItem [#1]}%
    \togglefalse{IsFirstItem}%
}%
```

where:

1. if this is not the first item, we add the rule,
2. apply the original definition of item, and
3. toggle the `IsFirstItem` so that we know for next time that a rule is to be applied.

Using this definition we can create our own `MyEnuterate` environment that has this behaviour (assuming you don't want this all the time):

```
\newenvironment{MyEnumerate}{%
    \toggletrue{IsFirstItem}%
    \let\item\ItemWithRuleAbove%
    \begin{enumerate}%
}{%
    \end{enumerate}%
}%
```

within this environment we redefine `\item` to use `\ItemWithRuleAbove` as opposed to the original `\item`.  At the beginning of this environment we toggle `IsFirstItem` to true so that it is initialized for this instance of `MyEnumerate`.

[image]

### Notes:

- I have used [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) for string comparison, but this can probably be done without this package if required.
- In [this answer to strange interaction between `mdframed` and item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47401/4301), egreg mentions that

  > Redefining `\item` can be dangerous and have impredictable results

  And also in:
  [LaTeX enumerate - bold item with non-bold text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23770/4301).

  However, in this case the redefinition is kept local to the `MyEnumerate` environment, so should be ok.

### Code:

Enumerated content copied directly from @Werner's solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newtoggle{IsFirstItem}% so we don't add rule above first item
\toggletrue{IsFirstItem}% personal preference: initialize variables explicetly at time of defintion

\newcommand*{\WernersHRule}{% Slightly Modified
   \par\kern\dimexpr.7\itemsep-\parskip-.6\baselineskip\relax%
   \hrulefill%
   \par\kern\dimexpr.3\itemsep-.3\parskip-.6\baselineskip\relax%
}%


\LetLtxMacro{\OriginalItem}{\item}% store existing definition of \item
\newcommand{\ItemWithRuleAbove}[1][]{%
    \iftoggle{IsFirstItem}{}{\WernersHRule}% only add \hrule if not first item
    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{\OriginalItem }{\OriginalItem [#1]}%
    \togglefalse{IsFirstItem}%
}%

\newenvironment{MyEnumerate}{%
    \toggletrue{IsFirstItem}%
    \let\item\ItemWithRuleAbove%
    \begin{enumerate}%
}{%
    \end{enumerate}%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{MyEnumerate}
  \item An item with descender p
  \item[a.] An item without descenders
  \item abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
\end{MyEnumerate}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item An item with descender p
  \item[a.]  An item without descenders
  \item abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried to use your solution for creating new description-like environment but didn't succeed (parameter for \item command is treated literally, but not as a parameter). Would you add solution for this to your answer? Or should I create new question?

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn: Have updated solution to properly handle optional parameters of `\item`.

Answer (score 10):

The standard list structures (`itemize` and `enumerate`) is made up as a `\list`. At the start of this `\list`, a condition `\@newlist` is set to `true` (via `\global\@newlisttrue`). This separates the first item from the rest in terms of the vertical space inserted. Here's an extract from the conditioning within `\@item` in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\if@newlist
  \if@nobreak
    \@nbitem
  \else
    \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
    \addvspace\@topsep
    \addvspace{-\parskip}%
  \fi
\else
  \addpenalty\@itempenalty
  \addvspace\itemsep
\fi
```

So, based on this, `\itemsep` is only inserted if we're not `\@newlist`.

Using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) one can now patch `\@item` and modify `\addvspace\itemsep` to insert a "decoration":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item An item with descender p
  \item An item without descenders
  \item abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
%
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@item}
  {\addvspace\itemsep}
  {\par\kern\dimexpr.7\itemsep-.7\parskip-.7\baselineskip\relax%
   \hrulefill%
   \par\kern\dimexpr.3\itemsep-.3\parskip-.3\baselineskip\relax}
  {}{}%
\makeatother
%
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item An item with descender p
  \item An item without descenders
  \item abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

On the left is a regular list, while the right shows the same list with the modified `\itemsep`.

If you want the `\hrulefill` to stretch the entire `\textwidth` (rather than `\linewidth`), you can use

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@item}
  {\addvspace\itemsep}
  {\par\kern\dimexpr.7\itemsep-.7\parskip-.7\baselineskip\relax%
   \hspace*{\dimexpr-\itemindent-\labelwidth-\labelsep}\hrulefill%
   \par\kern\dimexpr.3\itemsep-.3\parskip-.3\baselineskip\relax}
  {}{}%
\makeatother
```

which corrects for the `\itemindent`, `\labelwidth` and `\labelsep` inserted in the list.

The choice of a 70%/30% skip across the horizontal rule is somewhat arbitrary, but based on the definition of `\strutbox`. Together, they make up the entire `\itemsep`.

Comment: nice approach. But I would keep the `\addvspace`. After all, if the previous item ended in a vertical skip for some reason you want the maxium of both skips not the addition.  So perhaps start the patch code with `\addvspace\itemsep\vskip-\itemsep`  followed by your code. Also using `\kern`means you are dropping stretch and shrink and "perhaps" one would like to retain that at least above the rule.