# strange interaction between `mdframed` and `\item`

Tags: mdframed

I would like to understand (and to find a solution for it) the following problem. First, the MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{fancybox}


\newsavebox{\mcBox}

\newenvironment{monItemize}{
\renewcommand{\item}%
{\end{lrbox}%
\fbox{
\usebox{\mcBox}
}   \\\begin{lrbox}{\mcBox}}%
\begin{lrbox}{\mcBox}%
}
{\end{lrbox}
\fbox{%
\usebox{\mcBox}%
}%
}

\newcommand{\itemm}{}
\newenvironment{monItemizeMD}{
\renewcommand{\itemm}%
{\end{lrbox}%
\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=3cm]%
\usebox{\mcBox}
\end{mdframed}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mcBox}}%
\begin{lrbox}{\mcBox}%
}
{\end{lrbox}
\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=3cm]%
\usebox{\mcBox}
\end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}


\begin{monItemize}
\item aaa
\item bbb
\end{monItemize}

\begin{monItemizeMD}
\itemm ccc
\itemm ddd
\end{monItemizeMD}

\end{document}
```

In the environment `monItemize`, I redefine `\item`, which puts the content in a `fbox`.

In the environment `monItemizeMD`, I define the items thru a command `\itemm`, instead of `\item`, and the content lies in a mdframed-Box instead of a `\fbox`.

1. Question: If I use `\item` in `monItemizeMD` (of course, both in the definition and in the Instance of the environment), it fails to compile. Why ?
2. Question: How secure is it, generally speaking, to redefine `\item` ?
3. Question: Can i solve the problem of Question 1, still using `\item` ? Because my problem is, that, in many already existing documents, i have such an environment with `\item` redefined. And in my documentclass, i wanted to replace the `\fbox` by mdframed boxes.

Comment: Please have a look at this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56435/replace-item-with-myitem-to-box-each-list-member-with-an-mdframed It works well.

Answer (score 5):

1) `\item` is a vertical mode command, it starts a new paragraph, basically, but `lrbox` is like `\fbox` which is like `\mbox` a horizontal (LR) mode construct that doesn't allow vertical material unless you first nest a parbox or minipage or similar.

2) As noted the other day in [Use of \trivlist and \list in defining environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47057/use-of-trivlist-and-list-in-defining-environments) LaTeX uses lists everywhere. If you redefine `\item` you have redefined `center` and `verbatim` environments for example. **UPDATE In particular you would also be redefining mdframed**.

3) I'm not sure quite what the top level requirement is that you want to solve, you want to box each item of an enumerate and allow breaking within the box?

Comment: about 2 : just for science, i would like to know what makes in this case the interference with \item. the `center`

Comment: like all trivlist environments (actually `mdf@trivlist` variant here), the mdframed environment is implemented as a single item list so it calls `\item\relax` internally, so if you define `\item` to end one environment and start another it's bound to go wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Redefining `\item` can have dangerous and unpredictable results, as you discovered. If all you want is to box the text after `\item` with a width of 3cm, then

```
\newsavebox{\mcBox}
\newif\ifstartmonItemize
\newenvironment{monItemize}
  {\startmonItemizetrue
   \renewcommand{\item}{%
     \ifstartmonItemize
       \startmonItemizefalse
     \else
       \end{lrbox}
       \noindent
       \framebox[3cm][l]{\usebox{\mcBox}}\\
     \fi
     \begin{lrbox}{\mcBox}\strut}%
  }
  {\end{lrbox}\noindent\framebox[3cm][l]{\usebox{\mcBox}}}
```

will do.

Comment: Unfortunately, i want more. Depending on some boolean it should display the items in a `itemize`or in a `tabular`, with some extra feature. But this all works without mdframd... or wit another command name as `\item`. 

I think i learnt a lesson : `\item` should be used ... only for what it is intended to :)

Comment: As a linguist I really enjoy reading _i**m**predictable_, that's a great example of partial anticipatory [assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)) – thank you!

Comment: @dessert False friend, should be *unpredictable*, I guess