# Beamer itemize with odd even variation

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

i would like to obtain the following effect automatically

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,255,0}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=color1}
\item
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=color2}
\item
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=color1}
\item
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=color2}
\item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think with this approach you can get it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,255,0}

\newcounter{myitem}
\setcounter{myitem}{1}
\renewcommand<>{\item}[1]{\only#2{
\ifnumodd{\themyitem}{%true
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=color1}\stepcounter{myitem}
}{%false
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=color2}\stepcounter{myitem}
}
\beameroriginal{\item}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Graphical result:

[image]

> **IMPROVEMENT**

To activate or disable the alternate item coloring you can adopt a trick like this one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,255,0}

\newif\ifitemcolor % <= create a new conditional
\itemcolortrue %<= set it to true to activate the coloring

\newcounter{myitem}
\setcounter{myitem}{1}
\renewcommand<>{\item}[1][]{\only#2{
\ifitemcolor%
\ifnumodd{\themyitem}{%true
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=color1}\stepcounter{myitem}
}{%false
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=color2}\stepcounter{myitem}
}\fi%
\beameroriginal{\item}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\itemcolorfalse %<= set it to false to disable the coloring
\begin{itemize}
\item
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\itemcolortrue %<= set it to true to re-activate the coloring
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the example I created two columns with two lists: the list on the left has the alternate coloring disabled while the list on the right does not. Moreover the re-definition of the `\item` with additional `[]` allows to not insert text, as did for the two first elements in both the lists.

The graphical result is:

[image]

Comment: i had to add an empty default value to the `\renewcommand<>` so it becomes `\renewcommand<>{\item}[1][]{\only#2{`. is it ok like this? should the answer be updated?

Comment: It depends of what you have in mind.. I don't know why you need a default value in this case; maybe do you want sometime use this coloring an other time the standard provided by the theme?

Comment: it did not compile without the additional `[]`

Comment: I think you should be more clear telling which is your purpose; if it is, as I guess, having the possibility of disable the coloring, using square braces in my code is not the right way. At least, it is not as I will do. I can not say more without knowing your purposes, sorry.

Comment: i had no particular purpose. your original solution did not work in my example since the `\item`s were empty, but this is not a real case. with the additional `[]` in the macro definition it also worked with empty `\item`s, but i don't know enough tex-foo to understand why.

Comment: i found out the issue, thanks to PeterGrill's answer. the item command does not require an argument, so the definition should be something like `\renewcommand<>{\item}{\only#1{ %...
\beameroriginal{\item}{}}}`. is it ok if i update the answer?

Comment: Now I see your point. :) Actually, you are right: with additional `[]` you can even use `\item` without text. I will update my answer.

Comment: The `item` command does accept an optional parameter within `[]`. Also, redefining the `item` can be dangerous as per [strange interaction between `mdframed` and `\item`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47397/strange-interaction-between-mdframed-and-item).

Answer (score 3):

Yo can also have two definitions of the `\item` and altermnate back and forth between them. The alternating coloring is enabled via `\AlternateColors` called within the `itemize` environment.  Without this, the default coloring is produced.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,255,0}

\let\OldItem\item
\newcommand{\itemTwo}{%
    \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=color2}\OldItem%
    \def\nextitem{\itemOne}%
}%
\newcommand{\itemOne}{%
    \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=color1}\OldItem%
    \def\nextitem{\itemTwo}%
}%
\newcommand{\nextitem}{\itemOne}%
\newcommand*{\AlternateColors}{%
    \def\item{\nextitem}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}\AlternateColors% This enables the alternate coloring
  \item
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your solution misses the `<>` beamer stuff. will it work with them too?

Comment: Sadly, I know almost nothing about `beamer` - never used it. Best I can recommend is that you try it out. If you post a MWE, I am will test it and try to resolve any issues.