# Providing optional (unused) parameter to macro along with \tikzmark introduces spurious space

Tags: xparse

In my *overkill* solution to [Enclose an entry in an enumerate list in parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70436/enclose-an-entry-in-an-enumerate-list-in-parentheses/73307#73307) there is spurious space at the beginning of *some* (not all) uses of `\SpecialItem`.  I have narrowed it down to the MWE below where the macro `\SpecialItem` is defined with two optional first parameters, the first of which defaults to `\DrawLines`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\SpecialItem}{O{\DrawLines} o}{...code...}
```

In the `\SpecialItem` macro defined here, the first optional parameter is not used (the macro `\DrawLines` is not even defined).  So, using:

```
\SpecialItem  ...text...
```

is just fine. But if I specify the first optional parameter:

```
\SpecialItem[\DrawLines]  ...text...
```

I get spurious space introduced following the `\item`'s label as in the third list item:

[image]

### Notes:

- If `\tikzmark` is not used, or defined to be `{}`, then there is no spurious space.  I don't think this problem is related to `\tikzmark` as I have used that numerous time and not noticed this problem earlier.
- Moving the `\tikzmark` to be *before* the `\item` also does not produce this spurious space. But, I need it to be after the label as I want a reference to the start of this `\item`, and not to the end of the previous `\item`.
- In [this answer to strange interaction between `mdframed` and item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47401/4301), egreg mentions that

  > Redefining `\item` can be dangerous and have impredictable results

  Even though in the actual usage I am redefining `\item`, in this MWE `\item` is not redefined, just called via another macro. Hence, I do not think that the problem is related to this.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
%\renewcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{}%  Using this does not produce spurious space

\NewDocumentCommand{\SpecialItem}{O{\DrawLines} o}{%
    % #1 is not really used in this MWE, but is used in actual application
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
        \item\tikzmark{MarkStart}%
    }{%
        \item[#2]\tikzmark{MarkStart}%
    }%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item item
\SpecialItem SpecialItem without optional param
\SpecialItem[\DrawLines] SpecialItem with optional param
\item item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual `\item` command doesn't start horizontal mode, so a space after the closing `]` of its optional argument is ignored.

The problem with your macro is that `\item` is followed by `\tikzmark` which calls `\tikz` which in turn starts horizontal mode. Now the space after `]` in

```
\SpecialItem[\DrawLines] SpecialItem with optional param
```

is not ignored any more.

### Solution

Add `\ignorespaces`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\SpecialItem}{O{\DrawLines} o}{%
    % #1 is not really used in this MWE, but is used in actual application
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
        \item\tikzmark{MarkStart}%
    }{%
        \item[#2]\tikzmark{MarkStart}%
    }%
    \ignorespaces
}
```