# Add bold enumerate items

Tags: enumerate, bold

I would like to add bold items with `enumerate` in my report.

How can I do that using `\usepackage{enumitem}`?

Comment: do you mean the whole text bold? `\begin{enumerate}\bfseries \item ....`

Comment: Do you load any relevant packages like `enumitem`? Or do you use a special class. Please add a minimal working example.

Comment: With \bfseries, all the text of the item is bold. Also, I would like this style just for the number

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you want the whole item bold, you can write:

```
\begin{enumerate}\bfseries
\item The firs item
\item The second item
\end{enumerate}
```

If you want the number to be bold, you can do it by using the `enumitem` package and setting:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*})]
\item The firs item
\item The second item
\end{enumerate}
```

Check the `enumitem` [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for more info.

Comment: I have a) b) c) ... , not 1. 2. 3. ... but that is working. Thank you

Comment: just change from `\alph` to `\arabic`.  Edditing answer :)

Comment: If the OP is going to use this in every `enumerate` environment, it's better to use `\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\alph*)}`
 in the preamble.

Comment: I see a problem here: this answer is redefining the numbering style completely instead of enhancing it, i.e., making the number part bold.

Comment: with `[label=\textbf{\arabic*})]`, the dot after number vanishes. It becomes **1**, **2** like this

Answer (score 29):

This is in response to this comment by Raffi Khatchadourian on the accepted answer: "I see a problem here: this answer is redefining the numbering style completely instead of enhancing it, i.e., making the number part bold."

If you would like to avoid this problem with the top two answers, then there are two different solutions, one local and one global, using the `enumitem` package.

The idea for both is to use the `font=` key for `enumitem` instead of the `label=` key.

**Local:** Every time you want an individual `enumerate` environment with bold numbers/letters/numerals (whatever the setting is), just use:

```
\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries]
*your code here*
\end{enumerate}
```

**Global:** If you know in advance that you will want *every* `enumerate` environment to have bold numbers/letters/numerals (whatever the setting is), then put the following in the document's preamble:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{font=\bfseries}
```

---

Source: I read the [documentation](http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for `enumitem`, and both of the above solutions worked for me using TeXstudio and XeLaTeX compiler.

Answer (score 14):

If you mean having the item number in bold, you can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}]
        \item My first item.
        \item My second item.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For the one line enumeration items, if any one just want to do the numbering in bold then use paralist package with following code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
Here is my solution for one line enumeration bold listing 
\begin{inparaenum}[\bfseries a)] \item the first item,
\item the second item and \item the third or last item
\end{inparaenum}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `enumerate` package, you can do:

```
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries a.]
    \item First item
    \item Second item
\end{enumerate}
```

and get somthing like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the fancy solutions above do not work (e.g. because you are using exotic document types or nested enumerate and itemize environments or so), try a brute force solution:

```
\bfseries \item \mdseries
```

instead of just

```
\item
```

as usual. Of course, you'll have to do that for every `\item`.