# Add bold enumerate items on highest level only

Tags: lists, enumerate, bold, enumitem

Can somebody tell me how to make both the item number and the item itself bold - but only on the highest level of my list? So, 1,2,3 etc should be bold, while 1.1, 1.2 etc should stay normal. I'm using `enumitem`.

I've tried

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}]
```

but this turns every first number bold, also on the lower levels.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Additionally, a tip: if you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be accomplished for multiple lists by setting the style for each level of the enumerate environment using:

```
\setlist[enumerate,<level>]{<format>}
```

By also setting the *before* formatter, you can set the text of the entire item in a certain font, as you seemed to desire from your question.  Resetting for level two will set the fonts for the label and item back to normal for future levels.

An example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

% Change format of top-level list items
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label*=\arabic*,font=\bfseries,before=\bfseries}
% Reset formatting for subsequent levels; label type makes 1.1, legal-style labels
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label*=.\arabic*,font=\normalfont,before=\normalfont}

\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\begin{enumerate}
\item Three
\item Four
\end{enumerate}
\item Five
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image: Output from example code]

Comment: I changed this to reflect the desire of the OP to have the entire item (not just the label) be in bold.

Comment: Note that if you nest an `itemize` environment within the `enumerate` one, the items will still be bolded.

Comment: That is true.  You would need to tailor the `\setlist` command to the environments you are using, or else set the formatting for _enumerate_, _itemize_ and _description_ (plus any others that you created with the `enumitem` package).

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide a MWE, but I assume that you are using something like

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}] 
  \item first
  \item second
  \item third
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
```

which *does* make the second level `enumerate` items bold. This is not surprising, as you are forcing the `label` to be bold using `label=\textbf{\arabic*}`.

Instead, you should specify the font face separately, using

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*,font=\bfseries] 
  \item first
  \item second
  \item third
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
 ....
```

Here's a complete MWE to play with.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*,font=\bfseries] 
  \item first
  \item second
  \item third
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
      \item one
      \item two
      \item three
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\bf` is obsolete. You should use `\bfseries` instead. If necessary `\normalfont\bfseries`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain what you mean by the "lower levels" -- are you referring to nested `enumerate` environments, like the following?

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item
        \item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item
\end{enumerate}
```

If this is what you are referring to, then the following solution worked for me (see also **Local** in [my answer to a related question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347965/103825)):

```
\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries]
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item
        \item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item
\end{enumerate}
```

Using TeXstudio and XeLaTeX compiler, the `[font=\bfseries]` setting for the *outer* `enumerate` environment was *not* inherited by the inner `enumerate` environments.

Also, as a general rule of thumb, it is preferable to use the `font=` key for `enumitem` (as opposed to the `label=` key suggested in other answers) if all you want to do is to make the numbers/letters/etc. bold. `label=` completely overwrites the standard settings of enumerate, while `font=` just modifies them.