# tcbraster with two side-by-side lists in English and Arabic

Tags: fonts, tcolorbox, enumitem, arabic

I need to make the following produce two opposite lists in English (aligned to the left) and Arabic (aligned to the right) while understanding the reason behind the warning

> Language 'Arabic' not available for font(fontspec) 'Scheherazade' with
> script 'Arabic'.

Additionally, why aren't the `\hrules` drawn before and after the tcbraster?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[tuenc,no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
Ligatures = {
    NoCommon, % liga
    NoRare,% dlig
}
]{Latin Modern Roman}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Scheherazade}[ Script = Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}, Scale = 1]

\usepackage[english, bidi = basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = ids fonts]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Scheherazade} % [Scale = 2]{Scheherazade}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}{Scheherazade}

\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster,skins, fitting]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{ulem, enumitem}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns = 2,
        valign = center,
        raster before skip = 1ex,
        raster after skip = 1ex,
        blankest, 
        height = 3em,
        before = \hrule,
        after = \hrule
        ]
        \tcboxfit[ halign = flush left , right = 1ex ]{
            
            \textbf{\uline{Important Rules:}}
            
            \begin{itemize}[
                label = \textbullet, leftmargin=*, labelsep = \fontdimen2\font, itemsep = 0.5\baselineskip, %nosep
                topsep = 0.5\baselineskip, 
                font=\bfseries, before=\bfseries % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164268/2288
                ]
                \item First rule.
                
                \item Second rule
            \end{itemize}%
        }
        \tcboxfit[ halign = flush right, left = 1ex ]{%
                \textbf{\uline{%
                        قواعد هامة:%
                }}
                \begin{itemize}[
                    label = \textbullet, leftmargin=*, labelsep=\fontdimen2\font, itemsep = 0\baselineskip, %nosep
                    topsep = 0.5\baselineskip, font=\bfseries, before=\bfseries
                    ]
                    \item القاعدة الأولى
                    \item القاعدة الثانية
                \end{itemize}%
        }%
    \end{tcbraster}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: As to the first warning, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478541/5735 .

Comment: @JavierBezos may I know why the Arabic items are not right justified and the bullets are not drawn at the right margin?

Comment: Because the layout direction has not been changed. `babel` can’t know when to switch it and it must be done explicitly. See the muzimuzhi Z's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Additionally, why aren't the `\hrule`s drawn before and after the tcbraster?

`tcbraster` environment is not derived from `tcolorbox`, but more like a simple `minipage`. Therefore `tcolorbox` options `before=<code>` and `after=<code>` are ignored.

Furthermore, `\hrule` will only work inside tabular-like environments. Try `\par\noindent\hrulefill\par` instead.

To typeset arabic texts right-to-left, the `\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic} ... \end{otherlanguage}` environment is added (see [a guide on Overleaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Arabic)), and the option `halign = flush right` is removed from the second `\tcbboxfit`.

```tex
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[tuenc,no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
Ligatures = {
    NoCommon, % liga
    NoRare,% dlig
}
]{Latin Modern Roman}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Scheherazade}[ Script = Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}, Scale = 1]

\usepackage[english, bidi = basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = ids fonts]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Scheherazade} % [Scale = 2]{Scheherazade}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}{Scheherazade}

\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster,skins, fitting]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{ulem, enumitem}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
    \noindent\hrulefill\par
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns = 2,
        valign = center,
        raster before skip = 1ex,
        raster after skip = 1ex,
        blankest, 
        height = 3em,
        before = abc\hrulefill,
        after = \hrulefill
        ]
        \tcboxfit[ halign = flush left , right = 1ex ]{
            
            \textbf{\uline{Important Rules:}}
            
            \begin{itemize}[
                label = \textbullet, leftmargin=*, labelsep = \fontdimen2\font, itemsep = 0.5\baselineskip, %nosep
                topsep = 0.5\baselineskip, 
                font=\bfseries, before=\bfseries % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164268/2288
                ]
                \item First rule.
                
                \item Second rule
            \end{itemize}%
        }
        \tcboxfit[ left = 1ex ]{%
          \begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
                \textbf{\uline{%
                        قواعد هامة:%
                }}
                \begin{itemize}[
                    label = \textbullet, leftmargin=*, labelsep=\fontdimen2\font, itemsep = 0\baselineskip, %nosep
                    topsep = 0.5\baselineskip, font=\bfseries, before=\bfseries
                    ]
                    \item القاعدة الأولى
                    \item القاعدة الثانية
                \end{itemize}%
          \end{otherlanguage}
        }%
    \end{tcbraster}%
    \noindent\hrulefill\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the right half of the Arabic text, the bullets and their respective items should be drawn at the right since Arabic is a right to left language. Can you please fix it?

Comment: @Diaa Answer updated

Comment: Shouldn't the bullets in the Arabic text be aligned with the right margin as in the English text instead of going outside?

Comment: @Diaa I find the problem of different amount of `\item` margin reproduces even without `tcolorbox` nor `enumitem`. I'm not familiar with typesetting Arabic in LaTeX. Perhaps you can open a new question with a simplified example.