# Enumeration with bold-face roman numbers

Tags: enumerate

I want to enumerate my items by (I), (II), etc., for which I did the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(I)] 
 \item 
\end{enumerate}
```

Now I want to make them bold: **(I)**, **(II)**, ...

I followed [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/add-bold-enumerate-items) but could not find solution to my question, nor the techniques worked in my problem. How can we do this?

Comment: How should cross-references to enumerated items look like: bold or normal-weight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries(\Roman*)] 
 \item this is text
 \item this is text
\end{enumerate}
 \end{document}
```

[image]