# paralist-item numbers in bold

Tags: bold, paralist

I 'm using `paralist` package for enumeration (not `enumitem`). I want to have the item numbers in **bold**, like the image below.

[image]

The solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/add-bold-enumerate-items) (which is the code below)  doesn't work for me, probably because this was made for `enumitem` ([here](https://pastebin.com/GEFcnAr3) is the `log`-file).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist} 
\setlist[enumerate]{font=\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\begin{inparaenum}
    \item text1
    \item text2
    \item text3
\end{inparaenum}

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item text1
    \item text2
    \item text3
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

What can I do?

Thank's in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

The below may suits for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\theenumi.}}

\begin{inparaenum}
    \item text1
    \item text2
    \item text3
\end{inparaenum}

\begin{enumerate}[\bf(i)]
    \item text1
    \item text2
    \item text3
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yuvi thank's for your answer! I have **3** questions for you: **1)** Is it necessary to use both `paralist` and `enumitem`? **2)** Is there any global way like `\setlist[enumerate]{font=\bfseries}` in my code? **3)** Your solution **doesn't work with Greek numbering** (α', β', γ' δ',...). How can I fix it?

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας If you want horizontal list then you should use the paralist.sty package, \setlist[enumerate]{font=\bfseries] may works with enumitem package (I didn't test, just I am telling), and for Greek bold symbols, follow the tags \usepackage{amsmath} \mathversion{bold}

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any mention of \setlist[enumerate]{font=\bfseries} in the [documentation of the paralist package](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/paralist/paralist.pdf). It's rather part of the `enumitem` package.

However, playing with some `paralist` environments could be illuminating and get you somewhere close to what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist} 
\setdefaultenum{\bfseries 1.}
                             {\bfseries (a)}
                             {\bfseries i.}
                             {\bfseries A.}

\begin{document}

\section*{Customizing \texttt{paralist} enumerations}

\noindent
To customize enumerated \verb|inparaenum| lists with the \verb|paralist| package, we can set bold numbers through \verb|\setdefaultenum{\bfseries 1.}{}{}{}|, where lists will look like:
%
\begin{inparaenum}
        \item first item
        \item second item
        \item third item
\end{inparaenum}\\[1ex]
%
\ldots and items with nested \verb|enumerate|s will look like:
%
\begin{enumerate}
        \item text 1
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item text 1.1
                    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries $<$ i $>$]
                        \item text 1.1.1
                        \item text 1.1.2
                    \end{enumerate}
                \item text 1.2
                    \begin{enumerate}[$<$ i $>$]
                        \item text 1.2.1
                        \item[$>$ \emph{ii} $<$] text 1.2.2
                    \end{enumerate}
                \item text 1.3
            \end{enumerate}
        \item[\labelenumi] Note that setting a custom item label with \verb|\labelenumi| does not increase the item numbering.
        \item \verb|\theenumi| gives ``\theenumi'' whereas \verb|\labelenumi| gives ``{\labelenumi}'' (in bold plus a dot).
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

producing items which have bold numbers till it isn't re-customized at the list- or item-levels.

[image]

Comment: thank's for your answer! Is it possible to make bold every item number (re-customized or not) or should I re-define the default numbering in `paralist`?

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας So far as I understand, all item labels can be made bold with the `\setdefaultenum{\bfseries 1.}{\bfseries (a)}{\bfseries i.}{\bfseries A.}` command in the preamble.  Another way (independent of the `paralist` package) is to use `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\theenumi.}}` and the same with `enumii` `enumiii` and `enumiv` in the preamble too.  However, locally re-customizing any of these labels would normally break the bold fonts.