# Prevent titles at bottom of page—sometimes

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I have a book that contains both prose and poetry. I don't want a poem to start too close to the bottom of the page.

That's what the `nobottomtitles` option of `titlesec` is for. I don't want this to apply to the prose sections, however.

A solution would be one of the following:

- Let `nobottomtitles` apply only to `\raggedbottom` environments.
- Allow `nobottomtitles` to be turned off or on. (Can the package option be changed midway through the document?)
- Let `nobottomtitles` apply only to a particular section level—say, `subsubsection`.

Example to work with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[nobottomtitles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\newcommand{\poem}{%
\begin{verse}
First line of poem\\
Second line of poem\\
Third line of poem\\
Fourth line of poem
\end{verse}
}

\begin{document}

% Flush bottom for prose
\flushbottom

\section{Prose section}
\lipsum

\subsection{Prose subsection}
Can be at bottom of page

\subsection{Prose subsection}
Can be at bottom of page \lipsum

% Ragged bottom for poetry
\raggedbottom

\subsection{Poetry subsection}
\begin{verse}
Make\\
this\\
one\\
six\\
lines\\
long
\end{verse}

\subsection{Poetry subsection}
\poem
\poem
\poem

\subsection{Poetry subsection}
\poem
\poem
\poem

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well you can always do a manual break using `\newpage` to put that title that appears at the bottom of the page and send it to the following, in the last stage of editing. Of course, that's nothing automatic, I don't know if this will be useful for you.

Comment: Yes, this might be my fallback. Of course, I'd like to automate it using one of the above methods, as they should be algorithmically possible.

Comment: I just found the `needspace` package, which should solve the problem decently.

Comment: If you still need help, I know a cute trick using \rule and \vspace.

Comment: @JohnKormylo As far as my specific project is concerned, I think my problem is solved, but if it helps the general case it's probably worth sharing!

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185059/preventing-page-break-after-the-first-or-before-the-last-list-item/185496#185496